# `vim` takes me to lockout screen ( possibly X?)

Tags: vim, lock-screen

This just happened and I can keep reproducing it. If I type `vim`, or with any file name, I get taken to the lockout screen.

Was only doing this in new windows. The tabs and tmux sessions that I had open I could vim a file with no problem. So naturally I update and restart my computer. Now every time I type `vim` it locks me out and my screen says "no display" for a moment. I can log back in and my vim session is open in the terminal.

While I was typing this I did get locked out randomly. But it happens EVERY time I type `vim`.

Am running clamscan right now. (No infected in `/home`)

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

vimrc has not been modified for over a month (several restarts since that time)

these don't log me out

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

Update:
Second random lockout that is not connected with typing `vim`. Possibly X?

Git directories do not update if I add a file. Was testing because `git-commit` defaults to vim.

**ZSH**

I think this is connected to zsh (zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu))

If I switch my shell to bash I can execute `vim` with no problem

Moved `.zshrc` to backup, entered new session, typed `vim`, got logged out. I am using `oh-my-zsh` and `antigen` though, but they aren't connected without the rc file.

I DO NOT think it is related to zsh now. I can no longer clear the issue by using bash.